# Unable to create Redux store in angular2

Tags: angular, redux, store, reducers

I am trying to implement redux with immutable js in my angualar2 application

here is my Model :

```
export class TodoModel {
    id: number;
    text: string;
    isCompleted: boolean;
};
export interface ITodoAction {
    type: string;
    todo: TodoModel;
}
```

here is action

```
import { TodoModel, ITodoAction } from '../model/todo.model';
export function addTodo(todo: TodoModel): ITodoAction {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        todo
    };
}

export function removeTodo(todo: TodoModel): ITodoAction {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_TODO',
        todo
    };
}


export function completeTodo(todo: TodoModel): ITodoAction {
    return {
        type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
        todo
    };
}
```

here is my reducer

```
import { List } from 'immutable';
import { TodoModel, ITodoAction } from '../model/todo.model';

export const todoReducer = (state: List<TodoModel>, action: ITodoAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return state.push(action.todo);
        case 'REMOVE_TODO':
            return state.delete(findIndexById());
        case 'UPDATE_TODO':
            return state.update(findIndexById(), (todo) => {
                return {
                    id: todo.id,
                    text: todo.text,
                    isCompleted: todo.isCompleted
                };
            });
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
            return state.update(findIndexById(), (todo) => {
                return {
                    id: todo.id,
                    text: todo.text,
                    isCompleted: !todo.isCompleted
                };
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
    function findIndexById() {
        return state.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === action.todo.id);
    }
};
```

here is my store

```
import { List } from 'immutable';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { ITodoAction, TodoModel } from '../model/todo.model';
import { todoReducer } from '../reducer/todo.reducer';

export class TodoStore {
    store = createStore(todoReducer);

    get todos(): Array<TodoModel> {
        return this.store.getState().toJS();
    }

    dispatch(action: ITodoAction) {
        this.store.dispatch(action);
    }
}
```

here is my component on which I have use store

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoStore } from '../../common/store/todo.store';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  // todo: TodoModel;
  constructor(private store: TodoStore) {
    // this.todo = new TodoModel();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

But when I run my application I got the error

```
Module build failed: Error: F:/Tutorial/angular2/ngTutorial/src/app/common/store/todo.store.ts (7,5): Public property 'store
' of exported class has or is using name 'Store' from external module "F:/Tutorial/angular2/ngTutorial/node_modules/redux/in
dex" but cannot be named.)
```

[image]

I am not sure what I missing here, please help to get it working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line in your `TodoStore`:

```
store = createStore(todoReducer);
```

The type of the `store` property is inferred as `Store` and the property is public. However, `Store` is not imported from `redux` and that's the reason for the TypeScript error.

To solve the problem, you could either make the property private - does it really need to be public? - or could import `Store`:

```
import { createStore, Store } from 'redux';
```

For more information, see this GitHub [issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9944#issuecomment-244448079).